# How to install curl to jetbrains CLion

Tags: curl, cmake, libcurl

I have main.cpp and I need to install curl library to CLion, in Internet i find some answers, but they only for Visual Studio 2017. Ho have a experience with curl in CLion, can you help please?

Comment: Doesn't `CLion` use `CMake` ?  I expect a tutorial on how to use third party libraries with CMake should help.

Comment: This probably should help for the `CMake` part inside `CLion`: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704629/setting-up-curl-library-path-in-cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704629/setting-up-curl-library-path-in-cmake)

Comment: Not really, I don't even know how to add a third-party library to CMake, and what to do with the curl folder

Comment: Depending on what you downloaded you may have to compile curl from source or there may be binaries you can download for whatever compiler you are using. `CLion` is an IDE that you could use several different compilers or different operating systems. Some of the available choices will have automatic methods. I mean if you were on ubuntu most likely you are using the system default compiler and don't want to download curl yourself at all. You would use the package in your package manager. There exists package management under windows depending on your setup.

Comment: If you are on windows and using msys2 to deliver mingw, you most likely can install curl from the package managment in msys2 using a tool called pacman here: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/libcurl-devel?repo=msys&variant=x86_64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/libcurl-devel?repo=msys&variant=x86_64)